# Change dimensions of JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, preferredsize

Hello fine people of StackOverflow. I have run into a problem that I can't seem to fix. Before I begin I should give a warning that although I'm not a beginner, I'm not incredibly advanced either, so please if you can word your answers appropriately that would be great.

I can't control the dimensions of the JTextFields and I've used every way I know. Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ShapeCalculatorView extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

}

public ShapeCalculatorView() {
    init();
}

public void init() {
    setVisible(true);
    setTitle("Shape Calculator");
    setSize(500, 500);
    //
    GridLayout bodyLayout = new GridLayout(1, 2);
    GridLayout answerLayout = new GridLayout(2, 2);

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
    //
    JPanel bodyPanel = new JPanel();
    bodyPanel.setLayout(bodyLayout);
    bodyPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
    mainPanel.add(bodyPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    JPanel resultPanel = new JPanel();
    resultPanel.setLayout(bodyLayout);
    mainPanel.add(resultPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    bodyPanel.add(buttonPanel);
    JRadioButton buttonOne = new JRadioButton("Button 1");
    JRadioButton buttonTwo = new JRadioButton("Button 2");
    JRadioButton buttonThree = new JRadioButton("Button 3");
    JRadioButton buttonFour = new JRadioButton("Button 4");
    JRadioButton buttonFive = new JRadioButton("Button 5");
    buttonPanel.add(buttonOne);
    buttonPanel.add(buttonTwo);
    buttonPanel.add(buttonThree);
    buttonPanel.add(buttonFour);
    buttonPanel.add(buttonFive);

    String textLength = "Length: ";
    String textWidth = "Width: ";

    JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
    inputPanel.setLayout(answerLayout);
    bodyPanel.add(inputPanel);
    JTextField fieldOne = new JTextField();
    JTextField fieldTwo = new JTextField();
    fieldOne.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 2));
    inputPanel.add(new JLabel(textLength));
    inputPanel.add(fieldOne);
    inputPanel.add(new JLabel(textWidth));
    inputPanel.add(fieldTwo);

    JPanel calcPanel = new JPanel();
    resultPanel.add(calcPanel);
    JButton calcButton = new JButton("CALCULATE");
    calcPanel.add(calcButton);

    JPanel answerPanel = new JPanel();
    answerPanel.setLayout(answerLayout);
    resultPanel.add(answerPanel);
    answerPanel.add(new JLabel("Perimeter: "));
    answerPanel.add(new JLabel("Area: "));
    long perimeter = 5;
    long area;

    add(mainPanel);
    pack();
}

}
public class ShapeCalculatorApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ShapeCalculatorView view = new ShapeCalculatorView();

}

}
```

If you were to run this you would see that everything is fine except that the text fields are pretty high, and I'd like them to be a bit smaller. I've already tried setPreferredSize and that didn't work, I suspect it could be because I am using a GridLayout and as such the two textfields use up all the space, so setPreferredSize won't work. I also thought that maybe I could set the amount of rows to 3, and then in the second row just put 2 empty JLabels, but that seems a bit of a primitive way of dealing with this. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

EDIT: If it matters, I am able to control the width of the textfields with setPreferredSize, just not the height.

Answer (score 2):

Don't add a JTextField to a GridLayout directly as this will force the component to stretch to fill the cell. Instead either put it into a JPanel, or use nested layouts to achieve your GUI.

For instance (a terrible example, but one that uses your code):

```
  final JTextField fieldOne = new JTextField(10);
  final JTextField fieldTwo = new JTextField(10);
  // fieldOne.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 2));
  inputPanel.add(new JLabel(textLength));
  inputPanel.add(new JPanel() {
     {
        add(fieldOne);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Field 1"));
     }
  });
  inputPanel.add(new JLabel(textWidth));
  inputPanel.add(new JPanel() {
     {
        add(fieldTwo);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Field 2"));
     }
  });
```

Comment: Just clarifying so you're saying that if I were to put the textfield into a JLabel and put the JLabel into a JPanel I would be able to alter the dimensions with setPreferredSize?

Comment: @ViliMilner: I wouldn't put the JTextField into a JLabel, at least not usually, but more often into another JPanel.

Comment: @ViliMilner: see example. Note that I would not code it this way if it were my GUI.

Comment: I see. I'll try it both ways to see which one works and which one I like better, I'll try yours first as you obviously seem to be much more experienced. If I could vote up your answer I would, but my reputation is not high enough, so my apologies.

Comment: @ViliMilner: don't worry about up-votes. Just please keep us apprised on your problem and your progress towards its solution.

Comment: I tried out your example and the result is very weird, I get a textfield which has a very very small height, and I can't change the height. Regardless, it is 10:39 PM where I live and I am very tired and am not able to think straight. Hovercraft Full Of Eels thank you very much for trying to help me, you've already done more for me that any other member on this website. Hopefully by tomorrow I fix this annoying bug.

Comment: @ViliMilner: this is likely because you're trying to call `setPreferredSize(...)` on one of your components, something that you should strive to avoid. Let the components and the layout managers do the sizing for you.

Comment: "Let the components and the layout managers do the sizing for you" I don't know how to let them do the sizing but one way that I thought of is to set the GridLayout to 3 rows and add an empty JLabel in the second row, but that seems a primitive way of doing things. I could try it though.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't like this answer, I felt I should put it here for anyone who stumbles into the same problem I had. A way to solve this is to change  the amount of rows in the GridLayout and add empty JLabels where you see fit. Here it's a matter of preference and where you want the JTextFields and how small you want them.
Piece of code that I actually edited:

```
GridLayout gridFiveTwo = new GridLayout(5, 2);
```

And then the part whee I put in the JLabels.

```
    JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
    inputPanel.setLayout(gridFiveTwo);
    bodyPanel.add(inputPanel);
    JTextField fieldOne = new JTextField();
    JTextField fieldTwo = new JTextField();
    inputPanel.add(new JLabel(textLength));
    inputPanel.add(fieldOne);
    inputPanel.add(new JLabel(textWidth));
    inputPanel.add(fieldTwo);
    inputPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    inputPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    inputPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    inputPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    inputPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    inputPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
```

I don't like this answer, and hopefully someone knows a better way of doing this, but in the meantime this is what I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Set your layout manager to null.  Then you can use the .setSize property to set the size of your components / jTextfields.

```
this.setLayout(null);         //set this in your constructor

jTextField1.setSize(20, 200); // whatever you prefer
```